# Can't locate Algorithm/ExpectationMaximization.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, conda

I'm trying to use a Gitlab , where a perl module known as "Algorithm/ExpectationMaximization" is required as a dependency,

I have all the requirements installed in a virtual env. using conda on a linux op

now using the script seems to bug at the module I mentioned above for some reason I cant understand

I did cpan the module as I couldn't find it in any conda channel !

here I cpan it one more time to show you the logs of the installation, maybe you can spot the error and help me:

```
Running install for module 'Algorithm::ExpectationMaximization'
Checksum for ../.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AV/AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring A/AV/AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Math::GSL 0.26 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Math::Random 0.71 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Algorithm::ExpectationMaximization
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for A/AV/AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
----       Unsatisfied dependencies detected during       ----
---- AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz ----
    Math::GSL [requires]
    Math::Random [requires]
Running install for module 'Math::GSL'
Checksum for ../.cpan/sources/authors/id/H/HA/HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz ok
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----        HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz       ----
    Alien::GSL [build_requires]
Running install for module 'Alien::GSL'
Checksum for ../.cpan/sources/authors/id/J/JB/JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz ok
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz      ----
    Alien::Base::ModuleBuild [build_requires]
Running install for module 'Alien::Base::ModuleBuild'
Checksum for ../.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz ok
Configuring P/PL/PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz with Build.PL
Checking prerequisites...
  requires:
    !  Shell::Config::Generate is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Alien-Base-ModuleBuild' version '1.14'
  PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Build.PL -- OK
Running Build for P/PL/PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
----   Unsatisfied dependencies detected during  ----
---- PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz ----
    # Failed test 'csh'
    # at t/shell_config_generate__append_path.t line 50.
        # Failed test '[bsd-csh] FOO_PATH1 = foo bar baz'
        # at t/shell_config_generate__append_path.t line 47.
        # +------+------------------+----+-------+
        # | PATH | GOT              | OP | CHECK |
        # +------+------------------+----+-------+
        # | [0]  | baz              | eq | foo   |
        # | [1]  | <DOES NOT EXIST> |    | bar   |
        # | [2]  | <DOES NOT EXIST> |    | baz   |
        # +------+------------------+----+-------+
    # Failed test 'bsd-csh'
    # at t/shell_config_generate__append_path.t line 50.


Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/shell_config_generate__append_path.t (Wstat: 1024 Tests: 5 Failed: 4)
  Failed tests:  2-5
  Non-zero exit status: 4
t/shell_config_generate__prepend_path.t (Wstat: 1024 Tests: 5 Failed: 4)
  Failed tests:  2-5
  Non-zero exit status: 4
Files=13, Tests=80, 85 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr  0.03 sys + 125.48 cusr 15.11 csys = 140.73 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/13 test programs. 8/80 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:857: test_dynamic] Error 255
  PLICEASE/Shell-Config-Generate-0.34.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PLICEASE/Shell-Config-Generate-0.34.tar.gz
  PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3
  PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running Build for P/PL/PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'Shell::Config::Generate => 0' for 'PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz' failed when processing 'PLICEASE/Shell-Config-Generate-0.34.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Building Alien-Base-ModuleBuild
  PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
  ./Build -- OK
Running Build test
t/00_diag.t .................................. 1/? #
#
#
# HARNESS_ACTIVE=1
# HARNESS_VERSION=3.38
# LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
# PERL5LIB=../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/lib:../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/arch:
# PERL5OPT=
# PERL5_CPANPLUS_IS_RUNNING=18483
# PERL5_CPAN_IS_RUNNING=18483
# PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
# PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1
# PERL_USE_UNSAFE_INC=1
# SHELL=/bin/bash
#
#
#
# PERL5LIB path
# ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/lib
# ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/arch
#
#
#
# perl                    5.026002
# Acme::Alien::DontPanic  -
# Alien::Base             2.26
# Alien::Base::PkgConfig  2.26
# Archive::Extract        0.86
# Archive::Tar            2.24
# Capture::Tiny           0.48
# Digest::SHA             5.96
# File::chdir             0.1010
# HTML::LinkExtor         3.69
# HTTP::Tiny              0.070
# Inline                  -
# Inline::C               -
# Inline::CPP             -
# LWP::UserAgent          6.15
# List::Util              1.52
# Module::Build           0.4231
# Path::Tiny              0.114
# Shell::Config::Generate -
# Shell::Guess            0.09
# Sort::Versions          1.62
# Test2::V0               0.000130
# Text::ParseWords        3.30
# URI                     1.74
# URI::file               4.21
# parent                  0.236
#
#
#
t/00_diag.t .................................. ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild.t ................... Can't locate Shell/Config/Generate.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Shell::Config::Generate module) (@INC contains: t/lib ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/lib ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/arch ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2 .) at ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/lib/Alien/Base/ModuleBuild.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../.cpan/build/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14-3/blib/lib/Alien/Base/ModuleBuild.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at t/alien_base_modulebuild.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/alien_base_modulebuild.t line 4.
t/alien_base_modulebuild.t ................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/alien_base_modulebuild_cabinet.t ........... ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild_file.t .............. ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild_repository.t ........ ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild_repository_ftp.t .... ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild_repository_http.t ... ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild_repository_local.t .. ok
t/alien_base_modulebuild_utils.t ............. ok
t/inline.t ................................... skipped: test requires Inline 0.56 + Inline::C + Acme::Alien::DontPanic 0.010
t/inline_cpp.t ............................... skipped: test requires Inline 0.56 + Inline::C + Acme::Alien::DontPanic 0.010

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/alien_base_modulebuild.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=11, Tests=39,  7 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.03 sys +  3.27 cusr  0.26 csys =  3.63 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/11 test programs. 0/39 subtests failed.
  PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (Shell::Config::Generate); additionally test harness failed
  ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz
  JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory ../.cpan/build/Alien-GSL-1.02-3
Warning: Prerequisite 'Alien::Base::ModuleBuild => 0' for 'JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz' failed when processing 'PLICEASE/Alien-Base-ModuleBuild-1.14.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO one dependency not OK (Shell::Config::Generate); additionally test harness failed'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Configuring J/JB/JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz with Build.PL
Can't locate Alien/Base/ModuleBuild.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Alien::Base::ModuleBuild module) (@INC contains: ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2 .) at Build.PL line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 4.
Warning: No success on command[../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Build.PL]
  JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Build.PL -- NOT OK
  HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory ../.cpan/build/Math-GSL-0.42-3
Warning: Prerequisite 'Alien::GSL => 1.01' for 'HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz' failed when processing 'JBERGER/Alien-GSL-1.02.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => NO '../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Build.PL' returned status 512'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Configuring H/HA/HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz with Build.PL
Checking for GSL using gsl-config
Found GSL 2.4 (via gsl-config) installed in ../anaconda2/envs/py27
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wall"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wno-sometimes-uninitialized"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wno-unused-function"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wno-unused-value"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wno-unused-function"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wno-unused-variable"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-Wno-gnu"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking if /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc supports "-g"...Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at Build.PL line 212.


*** The test compile of 'tmp23873.c' failed: status -1
*** (the status means: errno = 72057594037927935 or 'Unknown error -1')
*** DO NOT PANIC: this just means that you may get some innocuous
*** compiler warnings.
no
Checking prerequisites...
  build_requires:
    !  Test::Taint is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Math-GSL' version '0.42'
Have a great day!
  HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Build.PL -- OK
Running Build for H/HA/HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----        HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz       ----
    Test::Taint [build_requires]
Running install for module 'Test::Taint'
Checksum for ../.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PE/PETDANCE/Test-Taint-1.08.tar.gz ok
Configuring P/PE/PETDANCE/Test-Taint-1.08.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Test::Taint
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  PETDANCE/Test-Taint-1.08.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for P/PE/PETDANCE/Test-Taint-1.08.tar.gz
cp Taint.pm blib/lib/Test/Taint.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Taint ()
chmod 644 "Taint.bs"
"../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Taint.bs blib/arch/auto/Test/Taint/Taint.bs 644
"../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl" "../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/typemap'  Taint.xs > Taint.xsc
Please specify prototyping behavior for Taint.xs (see perlxs manual)
mv Taint.xsc Taint.c
/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"1.08\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.08\" -fPIC --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot "-I../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Taint.c
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
make: *** [Makefile:331: Taint.o] Error 127
  PETDANCE/Test-Taint-1.08.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/make -- NOT OK
  HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory ../.cpan/build/Math-GSL-0.42-3
  HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running Build for H/HA/HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'Test::Taint => 1.06' for 'HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz' failed when processing 'PETDANCE/Test-Taint-1.08.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Building Math-GSL
Processing 2.4 XS files, GSL 2.4 (via gsl-config) at ../anaconda2/envs/py27
Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at inc/GSLBuilder.pm line 38.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at inc/GSLBuilder.pm line 38.
Compiler        =
ccflags         = -fPIC --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -I../anaconda2/envs/py27/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I../anaconda2/envs/py27/include
ldflags         = -shared -L../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
PERL5LIB        =
LD_LIBRARY_PATH =
/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -I.../../lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE -c --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -I../anaconda2/envs/py27/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I../anaconda2/envs/py27/include -o xs/Diff_wrap.2.4.o xs/Diff_wrap.2.4.c
Can't exec "/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc": No such file or directory at ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/Module/Build/Base.pm line 5553.
error building .o file from 'xs/Diff_wrap.2.4.c' at inc/GSLBuilder.pm line 336.
  HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz
  ./Build -- NOT OK
Running install for module 'Math::Random'
Checksum for ../.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GR/GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz ok
Configuring G/GR/GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lm
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Math::Random
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for G/GR/GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz
cp test1.pl blib/lib/Math/test1.pl
cp example.pl blib/lib/Math/example.pl
cp Random.pm blib/lib/Math/Random.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Math/Random.pm (blib/lib/auto/Math/Random)
cp test2.pl blib/lib/Math/test2.pl
Running Mkbootstrap for Random ()
chmod 644 "Random.bs"
"../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Random.bs blib/arch/auto/Math/Random/Random.bs 644
"../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl" "../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/typemap'  Random.xs > Random.xsc
mv Random.xsc Random.c
/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.72\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.72\" -fPIC --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot "-I../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Random.c
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
make: *** [Makefile:346: Random.o] Error 127
  GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/make -- NOT OK
  AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory ../.cpan/build/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22-2
  AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for A/AV/AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'Math::GSL => 0.26' for 'AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz' failed when processing 'HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'Math::Random => 0.71' for 'AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz' failed when processing 'GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/Algorithm/ExpectationMaximization.pm blib/lib/Algorithm/ExpectationMaximization.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/test.t .. Can't locate Math/Random.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Math::Random module) (@INC contains: ../blib/lib ../blib/arch ../.cpan/build/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22-2/blib/lib ../.cpan/build/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22-2/blib/arch ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi ../anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/5.26.2 .) at ../.cpan/build/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22-2/blib/lib/Algorithm/ExpectationMaximization.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../.cpan/build/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22-2/blib/lib/Algorithm/ExpectationMaximization.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at t/test.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/test.t line 5.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
t/test.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 3/3 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 3 tests but ran 0.
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.09 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.12 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:852: test_dynamic] Error 2
  AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
2 dependencies missing (Math::GSL,Math::Random); additionally test harness failed
  ../anaconda2/envs/py27/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
```

Comment: Looks like it's missing Shell::Config::Generate. I don't know why it wasn't installed automatically, but can you try installing Shell::Config::Generate, then trying again.

Comment: The module `Algorithm::ExpectationMaximization` installs fine with perlbrew `cpanm` on Ubuntu 20.04, perl version 5.30. Which linux and perl version are you using?

Comment: I tried `sudo cpanm Algorithm::ExpectationMaximization` on my little virtual machine which run Ubuntu 16.04. If failed on `'Math::GSL' is not installed, Module 'Graphics::GnuplotIF' is not installed`. And then `sudo cpanm Math::GSL` resulted in `PkgConfig failed with error message: Can't find gsl.pc in any of...`. Maybe because of a missing or unconfigured (with env vars to a path?) C library somewhere. I think trouble installing modules, not just for beginners, is a major reason why Perl is falling behind in popularity. Maybe it's just as bad in other langs? Not sure how to cure that.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit dense, but the most important statement in the output is this:

```
ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation
```

For starters, go back and install those modules. In this case:

```perl
Shell::Config::Generate
Test::Taint
Math::Random
Math::GSL
```

Now, what I don't know is why they weren't automatically installed as pre-requisites. I looked at [cpamn](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) and [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) and I didn't see where you would tell cpanm to recursively download and install all dependencies. Maybe someone else can help out with that.

Comment: Math::GSL requires a bit more work than cpan installation: https://metacpan.org/source/HAKONH/Math-GSL-0.42/README.md